How can I view only non-storage devices using lsusb, lsblk, or similar?
I'd like to see a list of connected USB Devices (eg. Usb Mouse, USB Keyboard) without having to go through a list of devices that includes internal and external storage devices (eg. internal HDD, USB Sticks, etc). I've looked at lsusb and lsblk but am struggling to find a solution.
Is there a grep filter or alternative command that could achieve this?

You could grep -v "Mass Storage" with lsusb but I wouldn't be surprised if there are some edge cases where that string might not appear.

sudo lshw -businfo | grep -i usb | grep -v storage

I'd personally filter out Host Controllers and Hubs because it's unlikely you wanna see them, so it'll be:
sudo lshw -businfo | grep -i usb | grep -v -E "storage| Host Controller| Hub"


The idea: querying each device listed by lsusb and printing only lines beloging to devices that are not registered as "Mass storage" devices;
Quite a bit of research has taught me (hopefully correctly, please point out if this is not as reliable as I'm understanding it to be) that whether a USB device is registered as a "Mass storage" device can be ascertained by querying the /sys/bus/usb filesystem hierarcy for the right bus / device pair and extracting, if set, its bInterfaceClass value; if this is 08, then the device is a "Mass storage" device.
Granted, this fits better as its own script, but for the purpose of quickly running it:
lsusb | perl -wne '
    use strict;

    my ($pbus, $pdev) = map {int($_)} /^Bus ([0-9]+) Device ([0-9]+)/;
    my $f = "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb${pbus}/${pbus}-${pdev}/${pbus}-${pdev}:1.0/bInterfaceClass";

    if (-f $f) {
        open(my $fh, "<", $f);

        my $bic = <$fh>;
        chomp($bic);

        next if $bic eq "08";
    }

    print
'

Comparison of the output of lsusb and the output of script above (notice the missing Seagate entry):
user@[REDACTED] ~ % lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bc2:aa15 Seagate RSS LLC Basic
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:5537 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB5537B
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04d8:0b29 Microchip Technology, Inc. U2417H_0B29_15083001
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2137 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB2137B
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

user@[REDACTED] ~ % lsusb | perl -wne '
    use strict;

    my ($pbus, $pdev) = map {int($_)} /^Bus ([0-9]+) Device ([0-9]+)/;
    my $f = "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb${pbus}/${pbus}-${pdev}/${pbus}-${pdev}:1.0/bInterfaceClass";

    if (-f $f) {
        open(my $fh, "<", $f);

        my $bic = <$fh>;
        chomp($bic);

        next if $bic eq "08";
    }

    print
'
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:5537 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB5537B
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04d8:0b29 Microchip Technology, Inc. U2417H_0B29_15083001
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2137 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB2137B
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

